# Django Admin panel- Adding a custome field in 'list_display' widget which is not an attribute of models class(without altering models.py)

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-admin

I want to add a field named 'count' to 'genre' class that gives the count of movies in that genre.
**models.py**

```
    class genre(models.Model):
        genre_name = models.CharField(max_length=20, verbose_name='Genre')

    def __str__ (self):
        return(self.genre_name)

    class movie(models.Model):

         movie_name = models.CharField(max_length=50,  verbose_name='Movie Name')
         movie_rating = models.IntegerField(default=1)
         movie_genres = models.ManyToManyField(genre, verbose_name='Genre(s)')
         added_by = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True)
         email = models.EmailField(blank=True)
         Date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)

    def __str__ (self):
        return(self.movie_name)
```

**admin.py**

```
    from __future__ import unicode_literals
    from django.contrib import admin
    from . models import movie, genre
    from django import forms

    class movieAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

        list_display=('movie_name', 'movie_rating','Date')
        search_fields=('movie_name',)
        filter_horizontal=('movie_genres',)
        list_filter=('Date',)
        date_hierarchy='Date'
        ordering=('-movie_name',)
        fields=('movie_name','movie_rating')

    admin.site.register(movie, movieAdmin)
    admin.site.register(genre)
```

I want to add **count** field in list_display

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write a method (either in the modelAdmin or the model itself) to get the required value. Then add it to the list_display like a model's field (without ())

```
list_display = ('somefield', .. , 'myCountMethod',)

    # in modelAdmin or model
    def myCountMethod(self, ...):
        # do some counts here
        return display_value
```